# Cisco VPN, Site 2 Site Via VPNC Gateway

Tags: networking, router, vpn, routing

i may be barking up the wrong tree here, been racking my brains over this.

I've been asked to setup a Cloud network which will house a number of services. They asked me to use our excisitng Cisco VPN to connect to it.

I decided to use a linux cloud vm as a gateway, this runs VPNC to connect back to the office and has scripts for maintaing the connection. My test windows server uses this linux box as a gateway. I've added routes from this WIN server through Linux to office network and all works fine, trouble im having is sending data back from home office to cloud.

Routing via the cisco VPN client IP results in a Transmit failure. I'm no cisco expert and thinking this may not be possble via cisco (Site 2 Site)

So far

**10.205.5.X            Cisco VPN (10.205.4.X)     10.205.1.X
CLOUDSERVER --- CLOUDGW ---------------------- OFFICEGW ------ OFFICESERVER**
.2                .1 + .4                        .1              .2

From Cloud Server i can ping Office Server but office server cannot ping Cloud Server , either using route with 10.205.4.4 as gateway of ping -S 10.205.4.4 10.205.5.2

Could anyone offer any advice as to if this is possible using cisco? RRAS is possible if this fails

tested using route with

Comment: Could you post all your routes. Also whats your existing Cisco VPN setup? Does it use an ASA for site2stie any connects and firewall rule for the access to this server.